# Creating autocorrelation plot with irregular time series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I'm doing a data science project where I'm trying to use previous police stops to predict future ones. I'm trying to make an auto-correlation plot of time vs geo-spatial longitude, but I keep getting an error when I try to make the plot. This is keeping me from finding the correct lags to make the ARIMA model.

```
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import to_datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

dataSet = read_excel('SeniorProject.xlsx', header=0,
                   encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
mini = dataSet[['TIME_PHONEPICKUP','GEO_LON']]
#print(mini)

#mini.plot(x='TIME_PHONEPICKUP',y='GEO_LON', color='blue')
autocorrelation_plot(mini)

pyplot.show()
```

Error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'

UserWarning: Requested projection is different from current axis projection, creating new axis with requested projection.
  ax = plt.gca(xlim=(1, n), ylim=(-1.0, 1.0))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError: '__name__'
```

Some sample data

```
   TIME_PHONEPICKUP     GEO_LON
0 2019-09-09 03:57:08 -105.025060
1 2019-09-09 03:55:39 -104.990248
2 2019-09-09 03:52:32 -104.925776
3 2019-09-09 03:49:44 -105.032151
4 2019-09-09 03:45:23 -105.029842
```

TIME_PHONEPICKUP is dtype: datetime64[ns], and GEO_LON is dtype: float64. Am I setting up the autocorrelation plot incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is coming from the time structure, maybe you should try indexing your time and see how the 
ACP goes.

Maybe something like this:

```
autocorrelation_plot(df.set_index('time'))
plt.show()
```

see the docs of pandas [pandas dataframe set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)